# How do I add a field in Django model whose data type is set to text

Tags: django, django-models

text_field = models.CharField(max_length=max) can I do this? I am using postgresql 8.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the type [TextField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/fields/#textfield). Like this:

```
text_field = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there should do the trick.  What issues are you seeing?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

If you're looking for a text blob, use:

```
text = models.TextField()
```

Comment: well this will create a field with data type varchar(100). I want to create a field with data type 'text'. Ex: fieldname(text)